# install Flask-ask on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, pip

I am trying to install the `"flask-ask" module` on my Raspberry Pi which is running `raspberrian-noobs`.
I am using the pip command `"pip3 install flask-ask"`
Then it is going through the downloading process and when it tries to install the module I get the

> **Error:**
>   Exception information:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in >main
>      status = self.run(options, args)
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, >in run
>      requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, >bundle=self.bundle)
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1230, in >prepare_files
>      req_to_install.run_egg_info()
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 326, in >run_egg_info
>      command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 716, in >call_subprocess
>      % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
>   InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 >in /tmp/pip-build-IHwQ27/cryptography

I tried running pip install cryptography before running pip install flask-ask
It got me the Error:

```
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1230, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 326, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 716, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-gOiMHb/cryptography
```

I also tried to download the tar.gz file manually form the pypi website but this ended with the same **Error.**

I would be happy if someone could tell me a solution?

Comment: Can you run your `pip install` command with `--verbose` so we can see the output?

Comment: Update your question and delete all the comments

Comment: Try running `pip install cryptography` before you run `pip install flask-ask`

Answer (score 1):

On the Pi, I've had better luck after upgrading pip3. Try

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

then try your install again.